# Laravel Schedule daily notification for each user on their preferred time

Tags: laravel, schedule, laravel-scheduler

I'm developing a task management app.
I need to send a daily report notification at the user's preferred time.
I did check Laravel features such as `Task Scheduling` and etc. But I don't find the right solution.
If I want to use `Schedule` I have to write a foreach containing all with all my users and check if it's the time to notify, every single minute, which won't be efficient!

```
       //Not Efficient Code:
       $schedule->call(function (){
            foreach(User::all() as $user){
                if ($user->preferred_time == now()){
                    $user->notify(new Notification);
                }
            }
        }
        )->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding this package which has convenient solutions for my situation: [Laravel Snooze](https://github.com/thomasjohnkane/snooze)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the loop outside of the schedule but I don't see a possibility how that would make it more efficient:

```php
foreach(User::all() as $user){

   $schedule->call(function() {
      // do stuff
   })->dailyAt($user->preferred_time);

}
```

Comment: thank you for the effort, and where do you mean I should write the code, is this meant to be written in the schedule function of `App/Console/Kernel`  ?